# Выскакивает ошибка:TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

Нужно написать функцию которая принимает в себя элементы списка в качестве аргумента и возвращает его с элементами число которых не превышает 20
Если делать без функции тобиш так:

```
j=[2,4,16,32,64]
j2 = [i for i in j if i < 21]
print(j2)
```

То это все работает
Но если через функцию:

```
def function(*array):
  finaly_array = [i for i in array if i < 21]  
  return finaly_array 

function([2,4,6,8,10,20,22,40,142])
```

То выбивает ошибку: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def function(array):
    finaly_array = [i for i in array if i < 21]
    return finaly_array


function([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 22, 40, 142])
```

Comment: Без * аргумент функции не сможет принять элементы списка да и функция ничего не выдаст:(

Comment: @YuraLevander https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcsEF.png

Comment: @YuraLevander эта функция всё замечательно принимает и выдаёт, код в этом ответе полностью рабочий

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, а я уж думал, что лоханулся, но вроде да все правильно.

Comment: Только что заметил что работает, но с одним условием return print (finaly_array)
Не знаю почему без принта мне функция ничего не выдает, но всо равно спасибо

Comment: @YuraLevander без принта никакая функция и не должна ничего выводить в консоль, всё правильно

Comment: @YuraLevander Не, надо так: `print(function([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 22, 40, 142])
)`

Comment: Имею ввиду вот так:
def function(array):
    finaly_array = [i for i in array if i < 21]
    return print(finaly_array) 


function([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 22, 40, 142])